# How to use textfield data as currency amount in visa checkout

Tags: ios, swift, checkout, braintree

I am unable to use `UITextfield` data as currencyAmount in visa checkout.
i have taken CurrencyAmount's variable as `a` and setting the itemMoney text to this variable.

What i am trying in my code:-

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var itemMoney:UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var lbl1:UILabel!
var a :Double = 0

@IBOutlet weak var checkoutButton:VisaCheckoutButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    a = Double(itemMoney.text!)!
    let purschaseInfo = PurchaseInfo(total: a, currency: .usd)
    purschaseInfo.reviewAction = .pay


    checkoutButton.onCheckout(purchaseInfo: purschaseInfo) { result in

        switch result.statusCode {
        case .success:
            print("Encrypted key: \(String(describing: result.encryptedKey))")
            print("Payment Data \(String(describing: result.encryptedPaymentData))")
            self.lbl1.text = "Payment sucessfull"
        case .userCancelled:
            print("Payment cancelled by user")
        default:
            break
    }
}
```

> Error :- Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads

Please help me

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: i am unable to use the textfield data as my currency amount

Comment: It looks like `a` is of type `String` (default value is ""), but you are trying to assign a `Double` to it. change `var a :CurrencyAmount = ""` with `var a : Double = 0`

Comment: @shallowThought see my updated question.Still i am unable to get it

Comment: Can you show the line where you are getting the error

Comment: @ØyvindHauge let purschaseInfo = PurchaseInfo(total: a, currency: .usd)

Comment: You are not "unable to use the textfield data as my currency amount", your code does not build. Also you have changed  the topic completely with your edit. Please take some time and effort before writing. Try to solve your issue. If you can not, describe the issue as detailed as possible and let us know what you have tried. We do not even know which line the issue appears.  If its on `PurchaseInfo`, show the definition of the initializer. Xcodes auto completion can help you.

Comment: @shallowThought i am getting error in this line "let purschaseInfo = PurchaseInfo(total: a, currency: .usd)" and the error is "Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads" and i have used visacheckout sdk framework.I wan to use textfield amount in this given line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a `Double`, but I see from the specs that `PurchaseInfo` expects an object of type `CurrencyAmount` (see section "Specifying payment details and launching Visa Checkout" from the [official guide](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/visa-checkout/client-side/ios/v4)).

```
let total = CurrencyAmount(string: "1.00")
let purchaseInfo = PurchaseInfo(total: total, currency: .usd)
```